# Breadth First Search vs A* with Manhattan Distance in a maze

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

Given an initial state and a single final state in a maze, is it possible to design a maze in which breadth first search expands less nodes than A* with manhattan distance as heuristic function? The cost of expanding to all nodes is 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. The intuition is your heuristic is more informed than BFS. This is also the base for proving it.

Formally:

- `h'(n) = 0` is also an admissible heuristic function.
- BFS is basically A* using `h'` as its heuristic function (since it always expands based on `f'=g(n) + h'(n) = g(n)`)
- `h` *dominates* `h'`, since for all `n`: `h'(n) <= h(n)`.
- Since `h` dominates `h'`, and is monotone, then the nodes expanded by algorithm using `h` is a subset of those expanded by algorithm using `h'`. More info and proof in [this thread](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1579/874), and in the [original article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4082128)

QED

Comment: Sorry, this proof is wrong. Please see my answer for an example of BFS beating A*.

Comment: @NathanS. Please point to the wrong step in the proof, because it is based on a theorem from the original paper inroducing A*, and only showing that all condition to this theorem apply. Do you think the theorem does not apply here? If so, why? Or do you think the theorem is wrong? The [original paper introducing A*](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci709s2c/resources/Mike.d/astarNilsson.pdf) Shows this in theorem3 and later uses the BFS example explicitly as an algorithm that always expand more nodes (see section IV, discussion and conclusions).

Comment: The answer is in the misconceptions paper I linked. BFS is not A* with a 0 heuristic. BFS can always terminate when the goal is generated, so it can have better tie breaking. See the example in my answer. The 1985 paper by Dechter and Pearl handles the optimality of A* in more detail than the original A* paper.

Comment: This article is irrelevant for the heuristic function at hand. It deals with *inconsistent* heuristics mostly, and when it does deal with *consistent* heuristics, it assumes `arbitrarily large sets of states`. None of these apply for manhattan distances as asked in the question.

Comment: To be clear, I added the monotony restriction to the proof that explains why conditions apply.\

Comment: This case doesn’t have anything to do with inconsistency, it’s BFS terminating when the goal is generated. To be clear, the question asks “is it possible?” If you give me any implementation of A* I can always find a problem where my BFS beats it similarly to my example. Put simply, A* is only optimal up to tie-breaking. Dechter and Pearl showed this in 1985 - but the theory is much more complex than you might expect. I’m only claiming that BFS beats A* in very specific circumstances, and only by a very small amount, nothing more.

Answer (score -2):

There are three ways this can happen in general:

1. When A* gets an inconsistent heuristic. A* can do up to `2^N` expansions of `N` states with an inconsistent heuristic. For an undirected graph an inconsistent heuristic has some states with `|h(a, g)-h(b, g)| > c(a, b)` even if the heuristic is admissible (`h(a, g) <= c(a, g)`). Manhattan distance is consistent, so this won't work in your example.
2. In a breadth-first search it is assumed that all costs are 1. Thus, when the goal is generated, it can terminate immediately knowing that it has the optimal cost to the goal. A* typically does not terminate until the goal is selected for expansion. Note that if A* was guaranteed that all edges have uniform cost (or some minimum cost), then A* could do the same.
3. A* is only optimal up to necessary expansions - those with `f(n) < C*` where `C*` is the optimal solution cost. If a problem instance has more than one state with `f(n) = C*` then A* could do worse if it did poorly with tie-breaking and BFS got lucky with tie-breaking.

So, now consider this example:

```
....._.     
SXXXXG.
.......
```

Here, a `.` is open space, as is the `_` cell. `S` is the start and `G` is the goal. The `X` states are impassible and the `_` cell can be reached/expanded, but you can't go down from that state to the goal.

If A* is unlucky it will expand the top route first (assume it expands largest g-cost first, but this also works with other tie-breaking). That route looks promising until it reaches the end, after which A* will have to expand the full alternate route.

Assume BFS gets lucky and expands the state below `G` before the `_` state. Then, BFS will be able to terminate without expanding the `_` state, and do fewer expansions that A*.

To be clear, label the states in the previous example as follows:

```
abcdefg
SXXXXG.
hijklmn
```

A* with unlucky tie-breaking will expand a, b, c, d, e, f and generate g (but not expand it). Then it will continue and expand h, i, j, k, l, and m, after which it can terminate with the solution.

BFS with lucky tie-breaking will expand h, a, i, b, j, c, k, d, l, e, and m and then terminate with the optimal solution. BFS does one less expansion than A*, because it doesn't expand f.

So, yes, it is possible for BFS to beat A* if the tie-breaking works out in favor of BFS.

Such examples will always be possible unless A* and BFS always expand states in the same order, or if further restrictions are put on the maze so that the heuristic is always perfect next to the goal.

See [this paper](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS10/paper/viewFile/2073/2500) for common misconceptions about A* search. One addresses the misconception that a better heuristic will do less work, and another addresses the misconception that A* with a 0-heuristic is the same as BFS.

--

**Note 1:** There is some discussion in the comments about whether the `_` state is expanded if it doesn't have any successors. The original A* paper states:

> Starting with the node s, they generate some part of the subgraph G, by repetitive application of the successor operator R. During the course of the algorithm, if R is applied to a node, we say that the algorithm has expanded that node.

Thus, if we apply the R operator and find no successors, we still have expanded the node. (They use a greek letter which I've replaced with R.) But, with a small edit to the map above, the `_` state does have one successor, so `_` is expanded by A* and a successor is generated (not the goal).

**Note 2:**

There is a question in the comments about Theorem 3 in the A* paper. That theorem states that there always exists some tie-breaking scheme for A* that will be at least as good as any other less informed algorithm. There are two problems with this theorem. First, it only states that A* is **capable** of beating another algorithm given the right tie-breaking, not that it will **always** beat every other algorithm. The second problem is that BFS is more informed than A*. BFS knows all edges have unit cost and A* does not. So, **the theorem does not apply to BFS**, because BFS has more information.

**Note 3:**

The question only asks "Is this possible." My answer provided here shows the precise conditions under which it is possible. The other answers (one of which has now been deleted) categorically state that it can never happen, and thus are incorrect.

Comment: Your example does not demonstrate what you intend: *"Then, BFS will be able to terminate without expanding the _ state, and do fewer expansions that A\*."*: But A* will not be able to expand the _ state either. Where would it expand to? So, the number of expansions is really equal (in the worst case that A* deals with the top route first). Note how the OP writes "the cost for expanding ... is 1", but at the _ state no such cost is made. No expansion occurs there.

Comment: @trincot It demonstrates exactly what I intended. A* will expand that state and find no successors, but it still expands it. I could easily put another successor after it that A* could generate if we wanted, but it wouldn't change things.

Comment: "and find no successors": that is not expanding.

Comment: @trincot Sorry, you're wrong. Expansion is not contingent on finding successors - you have to expand a state to figure that out. But, I can add another state to my example and A* would still do worse than BFS.

Comment: *"But, I can add another state to my example"*: please do.

Comment: @trincot Done. A* won't go past the `_` state because the f-cost goes up.

Comment: Indeed, so it doesn't expand. That's the point. Your definition of expanding is farfetched. In my understanding of language, when you "expand" something, it gets bigger. Apparently you define expanding as an intent, not as the actual act. That is playing with words.

Comment: A* will still expand the `_` state and BFS won't. BFS does better than A* in this example (given the tie-breaking I specified.)

Comment: I can only repeat what I wrote above. Your definition of "expand" comes down to "decision to try to expand", not to the expanding itself. That is odd. I'll leave it to the OP if they find that an acceptable definition.

Comment: After your edit: The paper uses that odd definition of "expanded". They are free to do so, but to be seen if the OP shares that definition. They seem to suggest that expanding comes with a cost, and in that case expanding is "true expanding", i.e. something gets expanded, gets longer. To say that something expands, and does not get longer, is playing with language in my opinion.

Comment: @trincot That's the definition from the **original A* paper**. I can't help if you think it's odd. That's the definition they gave.

Comment: Your example of "unlucky" is irrelevant. You are comparing potatoes to chickens, when using worst case of one, and best case of another. Use either worst case of both or average case. This "proof" contradicts theorem 3 in A* original paper.

Comment: The question asks “is it possible.” My example confirms it is possible. Read the paper I linked for further discussion.

Comment: This article is irrelevant for the heuristic function at hand. It deals with *inconsistent* heuristics mostly, and when it does deal with *consistent* heuristics, it assumes `arbitrarily large sets of states`. None of these apply for manhattan distances and mazes as asked in the question. (arbitrary large sets of states is relevant when costs are non discrete)